# "Is Acts 4:23-27 [NASB] previewing in a small way Rev 16:13,14, in that kings and rulers are gathered together against God and His Christ?"

Tags: revelation, acts, apocalyptic, christology

In **Acts 4:25,26**, the apostles, after being confronted by 'underhanded' chief priests and elders, after the death and resurrection of Jesus, are heard to be quoting David Thy servant, who, having been inspired by God's spirit, did say:

*"Why did the Gentiles rage, and the peoples devise futile things? The kings of the earth took their stand, and the rulers were gathered together against the Lord, and against his Christ."*

Could this be a preview of **Rev 16:13,14?**, where we are told of the gathering, by way of Satan's inspiration, of kings of the entire inhabited earth, to war against God and His Christ. In  **Acts 4:27**, we see that in Jesus' day those against him were Herod; Pontius Pilate; along with the Gentiles and the peoples of Israel. At 'Armageddon' we see this gathering of kings/rulers/peoples going against God and in particular His Christ, on a much grander scale, whose death, or at least defeat, is again sought.

Answer (score 1):

Act 4:

> 26The [1] **kings of the earth** rise up
> and the rulers [2] **band together**
> against the Lord
> and against his [3] **anointed one**.

Revelation 16:

> 14They are demonic spirits that perform signs, and they go out to the [1] **kings of the whole world**, to [2] **gather** them for the battle on the great day of [3] **God Almighty**.

I have numbered and highlighted the phrases that correlate in the two passages. Both talks about the kings of the earth gather together against God.

Is Acts 4:26 previewing in a small way Rev 16:14, in that kings and rulers are gathered together against God and His Christ?

Definitely, there are a significant number of words that correlate in these two verses. They are almost like parallel accounts.

Comment: Thank you for this, upvoted + 1. You could be the only answer here but there is time yet. @Dottard was the first to answer but after a few exchanges (I didn't think that he answered the Q.) then decided to delete same.